# MVC: Adding and Editing Identity Claim Role Name while using AAD authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I make use of AAD to sign in and authenticate the user, unfortunately there are no roles-based that I can use from AAD, so I need to rely on the Roles set in the DB, however, I don't know how to add a role for this user based on what's in the DB, without affecting the authentication cookies ?

I have however managed to add a role manually inside my `Startup.Auth` within the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, like this

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
           {
             AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
             {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
                return Task.FromResult(0);
             },
             SecurityTokenValidated = async (x) =>
             {
                var identity = x.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                //check the name, add additional claims 
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "Administrator"));

                await Task.FromResult(0);
              }
            }
```

However, as I am adding `Administrator` manually, I don't know how to change this based on the role linked to the user in the DB. I thought I could perhaps update the role once it hits my controller(which is my home/index), but struggling to find something that works.

I want to make use of `User.IsInRole("UserRoleNameHere")`.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution! Ultimately what I did was add a new claim to the ClaimsIdentity, signout to clear the previous identity stored and then signin again to add the new identity with the newly added claim:

```
            var result = (from U in db.Users
                          from R in U.Roles
                          join R2 in db.Roles on R.RoleId equals R2.Id
                          where U.Id == loggedInUserId
                          select new { R2.Name, U.UserName }).FirstOrDefault();

            ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", result.Name));

            IOwinContext context = new OwinContext();

            context.Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                isAdmin = true;
            }
```